# Getting arrayoutofbond error while running java code

Tags: java

1. I am getting arrayoutofbond error while running below given code,
   sometime it is running as expected and sometime it is giving error. 
   Could anyone help me where I am wrong.

   ```
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.BufferedWriter;
      import java.io.File;
      import java.io.FileInputStream;
      import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
      import java.io.FileWriter;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStreamReader;
      import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.Date;

      public class getFileContent{

       public void listFiles() throws IOException, InterruptedException{

           File directory = new File("C:\\ScriptLogFile\\"); 
           File[] myarray;  
           myarray=directory.listFiles();
           int i=0;
           ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss");   
           Date curDate = new Date();   
           String strDate = sdf.format(curDate);   
           String fileName = strDate;
           File file = new File("C:\\ExcelReport_"+fileName+".csv");
           FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file, true);
           BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
           String filename = null; 
           try {
               for (int j = 0; j < myarray.length; j++)
               {
                   File path=myarray[j];
                   FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream (path);
                   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                   if(path.isFile()){
                       if(path.getName().endsWith(".csv")){
                           filename = path.getName();
                           String line;
                           bwr.write(filename+",");
                           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                               if(line.contains("-")){
                                   String[] part = line.split("-");
                                   arrayList.add(part[1]);
                                   bwr.write(arrayList.get(i)+",");
                                   i++;
                               }
                               else{

                               }
                           }
                           bwr.write("\r\n");
                       }
                   }

               }
           }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           bwr.close();
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
           getFileContent gfc = new getFileContent();
           gfc.listFiles();
       }
      }
   ```

Comment: what makes you think there is atleast two elements in the array, that forced you to write `part[1]` and cause the havoc?

Comment: @Nishant: I doubt that's the problem. That line can only throw an exception if a filename ends with `-`, which is possible (and should be accounted for), but IMHO fairly unlikely.

Comment: @ruakh Do you see Array getting accessed anywhere else?

Comment: @Nishant: Good point. I was assuming the exception must be in code that's called from this class (and that the OP made the classic mistake of not posting the relevant code), but on second look, I don't see any calls to missing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a stack trace to see where the exception is raised. However you seem to be making assumptions about the length of `part[]`. Remember arrays are 0-indexed, the first entry would be at index 0 i.e. `part[0]`. Even then, in general there really needn't be many entries at all: `"xyz".split("-")` is an array of length 1 whose only element, `"xyz"`, is at index 0.

Comment: @Nishant: I am writing webdriver script and creating log content manually which has time for example, page landing time - 2 , so once all the script is executed, i use jave code to read .csv file and split text and time, using split. Split gives two part[0] and [1]. Part [1] has time which I save in .csv file for further use.

Comment: @NSanjeev/SK9: Stack trace is not available right now, as this issue appears sometime, further I was not expecting that I will get response from you ppl so soon, and that is really great. I have to wait for stack trace to appear next time. Thanks again...:)